# Borel sigma field on inifnite (countable) set

Tags: measure-theory

If $\Omega$ is inifnite (countable) set, then borel sigma algebra on that set is equal to $2^\Omega$?

What if $\Omega$ is uncountable?

Comment: i think its the result of $\sigma$-additivity

Comment: What is the topology? Borel sets are defined from the open sets. If the topology is trivial, the Borel sets are again $\{\Omega,\varnothing\}$.

Comment: let;s say its discrete topology

Comment: If every set is open, every set is Borel. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Note that $\{ \mbox{Borel} \} = 2^{\Omega}$ if and only if every singleton is Borel (because every subset of $\Omega$ is a countable union of singletons).

So, for example, if every point is closed (i.e. $\Omega$ is a $T_1$ space), this is satisfied.

Comment: This is for the case where $\Omega$ is countable, of course.

Comment: Let's say i want to define a discrete probabilistic measure on $\Omega$ (which is countable-infinite set). Then I should consider $2^{\Omega}$ measurable space?

Comment: Yes. This is obvious.